# Low variables & Matrix - Make a row act like an entry

Tags: matrix, low-variables

Is it possible to have a "main page" that pulls through a Low Variable tag pair with all the matrix rows, and then a view page to view each page with more details about that "one matrix row"?

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="franchises_for_sale"}
    {field}
    <a href="/businesses/franchises-for-sale/{some_uri_tag_like_page_uri}">View this matrix row</a>
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`row_id`](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/templating/field.html#tag-parameters) to get to the right row.

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="franchises_for_sale"}
    {field}
    <a href="/businesses/franchises-for-sale/{row_id}">View this matrix row</a>
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

And on the `businesses/franchises-for-sale` page:

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="franchises_for_sale" row_id="{segment_3}"}
    {field}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

If you want something more readable, try creating a column for a url_title (which you'd have to fill out yourself) and use `search:my_column="{segment_3}"` instead.

Comment: Thank you low, and if the row_id does not exist in that particular variable? 

eg: /businesses/franchises-for-sale/23123123123

i want to redirect to a 404 page however {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}

Does not seem to work?

Comment: You should probably ask Matrix' devs to add support for no_results in LV.

Answer (score 0):

Low had the best answer (use row_id to get the right row), but I wanted to answer Third_Hyperion's question in the comments (I'm trying to get involved with answering more, and I'm new)

For "No Results" I would consider using an If Statement prior to the matrix, comparing the row_id being provided with the number of rows in the Low Variables matrix field.

```
{if {franchises_for_sale:total_rows} < {segment_3}}
  {redirect="404"}
{/if}
```